# How can I run Linux shell scripts which needs root privilege from a web page

Tags: linux, shell-script, apache-httpd

I'm trying to run a linux shell script which requires root privilege via Apache, Is there any way to run scripts which needs root privilege, rather than setting suid and sudo privilege to Apache.

I'm trying to edit files like control panels do, eg in Plesk "sw-cp-server" can edit root files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is no matter how you slice it, if an unprivileged user can *write* to the script file, you are leaving a door open to let that user do anything since in this case s/he can modify the script.  However, there's no need to do that, since it could owned root and set 0700 if you like.

> rather than setting suid and sudo privilege to Apache

You don't have to set suid on anything, and you can use sudo so that apache can only execute that script.  If apache runs as user `httpd`, add to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
httpd ALL = NOPASSWD: /foo/bar/scripts/foobar.sh
```

Substitute the actual path for the script there.  The invocation will then have to use `sudo /foo/bar/scripts/foobar.sh`.  But that is the only thing user `httpd` will be allowed to do that way.

See `man 5 sudoers` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to run scripts that would require root priveleges via Apache would be to give Apache the required set of privileges to make the modifications you require.

Another option (and this is a dirty workaround) would be to have Apache write to a file and a daemon run on the server to check those files that Apache has written to and take action based on what has been written to the file by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run Apache with root privileges (and you shouldn't), then you can write a small wrapper program for the script that you give SUID permissions (`chmod 4755`) and has `root` as owner. That wrapper program can then call the script, which will execute  with the right permissions. No other scripts will thus be 'elevated', but of course you need to take care that the contents  of the script cannot be changed by just anyway.